# Fuzzy topology : references

Tags: textbook-recommendation, gn.general-topology, fuzziness

Hey. I'm looking for references in fuzzy topology. Does anyone know a good book ?

Comment: I'm sure it's not what you want, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem comes to mind :)

Comment: What do you mean by the term "fuzzy topology"? A point-set topology build up within a fuzzy-set framework (e.g. with a graded notion of openness)?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the field enough to evaluate these options, 
but there are at least two books with the title "Fuzzy Topology," and another specifically
focusing on metric spaces:

- 1997, Liu & Luo, *Fuzzy Topology*, World Scientific.
- 1999, Diamond & Kloeden, *Metric Spaces of Fuzzy Sets*, Elsevier.
- 2005, Palaniappan, *Fuzzy Topology*, Alpha Science Int'l Ltd.

All three can be previewed in Google Books.

Comment: I found thoses. I just want an inside view. But thanks anyway !